# angular 2: How to access a variable in wrapping div?

Tags: angular

I wrote the following template in Angular 2 project:

```
    <tr *ngFor = "let item of listOfBooks">
      <button #title (click)="changeTitle(title, item)">{{item.name}}</button>
    </tr>
```

When I wrote the code, I expected that once I click on the button, two parameters will be passed to function changeTitle. While 'title' is passed successfully, 'item' is 'undefined'. I can clearly say that 'item' in 'tr' tag is not undefined, since "{{item.name}}" gives something "real".

Do you know what is the problem ?

Comment: This just works. Can you reproduce in a plunker or at least show how you check in `changeTitle` that `item` is undefined?

Comment: Unrelated, but a <tr> should contain <td> or <th>, not buttons.

Comment: You're right. It works. I don't know why but when I wrote it in HTML, ng serve didn't refresh it automatically. Do you have any tips how to know if html is not refreshed automatically?